# what is the name and password for transfer server?

Tags: mac, virtualbox, file-transfer

I want to transfer files between my Windows 7 unlimited computer and my Mac VirtualBox machine.
I followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QKs_N4s92t4).

1. I did not set a password for my Windows computer
2. While connecting, it asks this:

[image: Screenshot of my VM]

What exactly is my name and password? Where is it?
I entered all of the things needed but it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You Solution can be found in [this SuperUser Question](https://superuser.com/questions/39432/can-i-smb-into-a-windows-file-share-without-a-password#39436)

If you want to use smb without a password, you have some options to bypass the "blank password issue", but it basically won't work. The Samba Service in Windows 7 simply does not allow you to do so.

I your specific case, the Username would be your Win7 Account Name and the password would be blank. But since Win7 (smb) does not allow a blank password for authentication you can not log in.